# How do I set up a successful authentication callback with passport.js using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, facebook, authentication, passport.js

I'm trying to set up facebook authentication in my MEAN stack application. The code of written works to the point of authenticating the user on facebook, but when it is sent back to my application, the callback function runs but the `passport.authenticate('facebook'.....` part doesnt not.

This is my code in the routes file:

```
    app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function() {
        console.log('callback')
         passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            successRedirect : '/',
            failureRedirect : '/fail'
          })
    });
```

"callback" is outputted in the console but then the application just is in a state of loading until it times out.

This is the passport.js file I used to configure passport:

```
// config/passport.js



// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy    = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

// load up the user model
var User       = require('../app/models/user');

// load the auth variables
var configAuth = require('./auth');


module.exports = function(passport) {


    passport.use('facebook', new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID        : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret    : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL     : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
        profileFields: ["emails", "displayName"]
    },

      // facebook will send back the tokens and profile
      function(access_token, refresh_token, profile, done) {
        // asynchronous
        process.nextTick(function() {

          // find the user in the database based on their facebook id
          User.findOne({ 'id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {

            // if there is an error, stop everything and return that
            // ie an error connecting to the database
            if (err)
              return done(err);

              // if the user is found, then log them in
              if (user) {
                return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
              } else {
                // if there is no user found with that facebook id, create them
                var newUser = new User();

                // set all of the facebook information in our user model
                newUser.fb.id    = profile.id; // set the users facebook id                 
                newUser.fb.access_token = access_token; // we will save the token that facebook provides to the user                    
                newUser.fb.firstName  = profile.name.givenName;
                newUser.fb.lastName = profile.name.familyName; // look at the passport user profile to see how names are returned
                newUser.fb.email = profile.emails[0].value; // facebook can return multiple emails so we'll take the first

                // save our user to the database
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                  if (err)
                    throw err;

                  // if successful, return the new user
                  return done(null, newUser);
                });
             } 
          });
        });
    }));


}
```

Comment: Add some logs in you passport file? See where it goes?

Comment: @DrakaSAN it seems to not run the passport file at all. I've added console.log(x) to various parts of the passport file and it doesn't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your `/auth/facebook/callback` you are executing `passport.authenticate` inside your route handler and not as a middleware, ie. what is referred as [custom callback](http://passportjs.org/docs#custom-callback) in the documentation. This call returns a function but you do not execute it so nothing happens.

You will need to either run `passport.authenticate` here as a middleware (which is [the usual way](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate)), or actually use the `req`, `res`, and `next` arguments your route handler receives (but you omit) and pass them to the `authenticate` call within the route handler.

The middleware way is shown in the [documentation of `passport-facebook`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook#authenticate-requests), ie. for you it would be:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/',
        failureRedirect : '/fail'
    })
);
```

If you for some reason would wish to use custom callback, you'd need something like below this:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, user, info) {
        // Do your things and then call `req.logIn` and stuff
    })(req, res, next);
});
```